# How to make index-value matching for index table (from skeleton to flesh)?

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have data.frame which filled with numeric position index, and I have also minimal data.frame where numeric index paired with p.value. However, I intend to search p.value of the numeric index in `indexDF` and construct p.value table for `indexDF` which is used for fisher method. Are there any functions for value matching from index (skeleton) to p.value (flesh) ? How can I make this happen efficiently? How can I search the p.value of a numeric index in `indexDF` and build its pvalue table for combing pvalue by row? Can anyone give me the possible idea to ease this process?  Any idea?

Here is index-value pair table where numeric index with value (which is used for searching pvalue by given numeric index):

**Edit** :

`valuePairDB` is updated. Note that some different numeric index may have identical p.value, but that's not duplicate.

```
valuePairDB <- data.frame(
    subjIdx = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7, 8 ,9 ,10 ,11 ,12 ,13 ,14 ,15 ,16 ,
                17 ,18, 19, 20, 21, 22),
    pvalue = c(1e-48 ,1e-07 ,1e-10 ,1e-08 ,1e-04 ,1e-15 ,1e-04 ,1e-04 ,1e-38 ,1e-54,
               1e-21 ,1e-14 ,1e-12, 1e-21, 1e-07, 1e-32 ,1e-04 ,1e-49, 1e-13 ,1e-13,
               1e-11 ,1e-05))
```

Here is the index table I am gonna work with for fisher method:

```
indexDF <- data.frame(
    sub1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7, 8 ,9 ,10 ,11 ,12 ,13 ,14 ,15 ,16 ,
           17 ,18, 19, 20, 21, 22),
    sub2=c(10 ,12 ,12, 20 ,14 ,20 ,21 ,16 ,17,1 ,18,2 ,19,5,
           21,8,9,2,13,5,7,8),
    sub3=c(18,18,18 ,0,20 ,0 ,0,22 ,22,0,0 ,18,0 ,20,0 ,22,
           0 ,12 ,0 ,14 ,15 ,16)
)
```

Here is the desired data.frame to fill pvalue of numeric index in `indexDF` (`desiredDF` is just minimal representation of desired output)

```
desiredDF <- data.frame(
    sub1.pv=c(1e-48,1e-07,1e-10,1e-08),
    sub2.pv=c(1e-54,1e-14,1e-14,1e-13),
    sub3.pv=c(1e-49,1e-49,1e-49,0)
)
```

I want to find out pvalue of each numeric index in `indexDF` from `valuePairDF` and build new data.frame (tabular data) for fisher method:

```
fisher <- pchisq(chisq, df, lower.tail = FALSE)
cmb.pv <- apply(desiredDF,1, fisher)
```

How can I make this sort of index-value matching for `indexDF` and construct corresponding pvalue table? How can I achieve my desired output? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you have so many duplicates in your `valuePairDF`?

Comment: `indexDF[] <-  lapply(indexDF, function(col) valuePairDF$pvalue[match(col, valuePairDF$subjIdx)])` would be one way to do it. But I really don't see why you need duplicates in this case.

Comment: @Psidom I updated the post with correct `valuePairDF`, where the different numeric index may have identical p.value, but that's not duplicate. Is that possible to continue your thought on my update? Thank you

Comment: @Psidom sorry for this simple question: what is the advantage of using a scope like this `index[ ]`? I just want to know the idea behind. Thank you

Comment: Not much advantage I know of, but it provides a data frame container to hold your new data so that you don't have to convert the returned lists to a data frame, which saves some typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to loop through your `indexDF` and for each column, use match to find out the rows, where `index` matches the subject index and replace it with the corresponding `p.value`:

```
indexDF[] <- lapply(indexDF, function(col) valuePairDB$pvalue[match(col, valuePairDB$subjIdx)])

head(indexDF)
#   sub1  sub2  sub3
#1 1e-48 1e-54 1e-49
#2 1e-07 1e-14 1e-49
#3 1e-10 1e-14 1e-49
#4 1e-08 1e-13    NA
#5 1e-04 1e-21 1e-13
#6 1e-15 1e-13    NA
```

If you need to replace `NA` with 0, you can do `indexDF[is.na(indexDF)] <- 0`

---

A corresponding `dplyr` solution would be use `mutate_all`:

```
indexDF %>% mutate_all(funs(valuePairDB$pvalue[match(., valuePairDB$subjIdx)]))
```

Comment: Is that possible to use `dplyr` to make this more elegant? If I am gonna try `dplyr`, how can I do that same thing? Thank you